# Single page web apps; Load all templates at once?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, mustache

I'm writing my first single-page web app (HTML5/javascript over Ruby powered JSON API). I'm using mustache.js templates to plug in values returned by the JSON API into markup. Given that,

Which is the preferred practice?

1. Delivering all <script type="text/template"> templates to the page with the initial request.

   1. Call the JSON API and plug in the values
2. Delivering the skeleton of the page, and then

   1. Ajax in the template
   2. Call the JSON API and plug in the values

Thanks.

Comment: Ben, it really depends. If I'd have pages with limited templates, I'd inline them (term 'bake'). If the templates were more than 'a few' I'd consider AJAX-ing them with GET and made sure caching is enabled - to limit the amount of data sent over.

Answer (score 0):

Either can work, depending on the size of the page, number of templates, cachability of the initial request, etc. Generally, I prefer a third option:

3. Delivering the skeleton of the webpage, and then

1. Compile the templates to JavaScript functions with hogan.js and concatenate into a single `templates.js`.
2. Load the resulting `templates.js` file (with appropriate headers and such so that the browser gets its cache on).
3. Call the JSON API and plug in the values.